# Cannot set up Thuderbird email accounts

Tags: thunderbird

I can't set up Thunderbird email accounts. I have Thunderbird installed on several operating systems with no problems. I even uninstalled Ubuntu 18.04 & reinstalled it. I get a message saying that either the email or the password is wrong.

I have 3 different email accounts on Comcast.net but can't get any of them working on Ubuntu 18.04. Works find on Windows 7 & Linux Mint. I guess I will uninstall Ubuntu & forget about it if I can't get this resolved!

Comment: There are a lot of things that can cause this...  For instance, I always forget that my number pad is not set to num lock by default (ie. the numbers on the num pad do not work unless I press Num Lock).

It could also be a configuration error in thunderbird (ie. port number, server, etc.).

Finally, it could be an issue with your firewall or machine configuration.  You never know until you rule out all the possibilities.  Usually it's something pretty simple.

Comment: If you don't include more information about the configuration, such as screenshot showing how you actually configure it, it's impossible to diagnose. Include as *much* information as possible, if possible including screenshots of account setups on a platform where it works.

Comment: I don't use the key pad. And I can see if the caps lock is on as I type in the user name. I have compared all of the information on the Ubuntu OS to the information in Windows 7. Everything looks the same. Thunderbird just does not work on Ubuntu! It was working with version 17.10 but then stopped working when I upgraded to 18.04. I have uninstalled & reinstalled Ubuntu & upgraded to 18.10. The error message says that it could not verify & says could the user name or password be wrong. I'm using the same user name & password on all of the different operating systems.

Comment: The answer is to use imap.ge.xfinity.com instead of imap.comcast.net. Took a lot of searching to find this answer. Hope this helps others with this problem. Strange that other operating systems still work with imap.comcast.net.

Answer (score 1):

## The answer is to use `imap.ge.xfinity.com`

instead of `imap.comcast.net`.

This seems to be a [`systemd` bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1805027). Those who are affected by this bug are encouraged to list themselves "affected" in the bug linked report.